# Using jQuery for alternating png transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very basic question. I have a very simple web design utilizing a png with transparency, overlaying another base image. The idea here is that it cycles visibility continously, fading in quickly, displaying for a longer interval, fading out quickly, and remaining invisible for an equal longer interval, basically replicating the behavior of an animated GIF from back in the day. The png starts with display set to none.

My problem is jQuery doesn't seem to have a "pause" or "delay" event handler to help here. There are numerous plugins filling the gap, but I'd rather not include one if there's a simple way that I'm missing. That might require falling back on setInterval or setTimeOut, but I'm uncertain of the syntax to do that.

What I want schematically is something like:

```
--loop start--

$("#pngOverlay").fadeIn(1000);

(5000 delay)  // using setTimeout or setInterval if jQuery method unavailable

$("#pngOverlay").fadeOut(1000);

(5000 delay)

--loop repeat--
```

The following does the behavior once, so I guess if this could be wrapped in a loop it might work, but it doesn't strike me as elegant or the right way.

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#pngOverlay").fadeIn(1000);
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#pngOverlay").fadeOut(1000);
    }, 10000);
```

Thanks for any suggestions. I would just use GIFs, but need the transparency for this. (In the old days, we used animated GIFs and we *liked* them...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
setInterval(function()
{
    var elm = $('#pngOverlay');
    if (elm.is(':hidden'))
        elm.fadeIn(1000);
    else
        elm.fadeOut(1000);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. This is the most elegant one, wouldn't have thought to use conditional. One odd thing: the png was hidden using CSS display:none attr, not visibility:hidden. When I try using visibility:hidden with this script, it no longer works. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function showimage(){
     $("#pngOverlay").fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout('hideimage()',5000);
}

function hideimage(){
      $("#pngOverlay").fadeOut(1000);
    setTimeout('showimage()',5000);

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    showimage();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of a callback loop. Both this and the following comment work for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an [animated PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG)?

Comment: or not having annoying animations for the sake of it?

Comment: I thought about using ANPG, but don't browser support really isn't there yet. And I wanted to learn how to do it w/jQuery, which I'm using for a lot of other stuff now (but obviously need more practice!). FWIW, the animation is "quiet" – meant to be very subtle and not observed immediately, thus the need for a long interval.

Answer (score 0):

One trick I have seen is to have jQuery carry out an animation for 5000 milliseconds that has no visible effect.

```
  $("#pngOverlay").animate({opacity:1}, 5000);
```

If the opacity of the item was 1 to start with then it does not have a visible effect but it does pause for 5 seconds.

Comment: Good tip. I played with animate but didn't think about using it for de facto nothing. I wish jQuery had timers/delays built-in...